# apache giving error while accessing apex admin

Tags: oracle, apache, oracle-apex

i have deployed ords.war on Apache tomcat on linux OS to run oracle apex 18.2 , i have done all configuration and apache was started normally. I am able to access

```
http://host:8080/ords
```

While accessing apex admin using below url

```
http://host:8080/apex/apex_admin
```

It Showing me below error

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /apex/apex_admin

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
```

Suggestion required for above error however in log files i am getting below messages

```
03-Dec-2018 21:26:23.590 WARNING [main] . *** jdbc.MaxLimit in configuration |apex|rt| is using a value of 10, this setting may not be sized adequately for a production environment ***
03-Dec-2018 21:26:23.590 WARNING [main] . *** jdbc.InitialLimit in configuration |apex|rt| is using a value of 3, this setting may not be sized adequately for a production environment ***
03-Dec-2018 21:26:23.791 INFO [main] . Oracle REST Data Services initialized
```

Comment: If you want to use `/apex/` as your ORDS URL, you can rename `ords.war` to `apex.war`. Otherwise you probably want http://host:8080/ords/apex_admin

Comment: Yes , it worked now thanks

Comment: Can you tell me why are exceptions in Log files ??

Comment: They're just warnings, it's very common. They look normal for a development environment.

Comment: ok thanks for the time and support